# <2k users can't edit own posts or community wiki posts with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: bug, edits, community-wiki, accessibility, keyboard-shortcuts

I have tested this on Worldbuilding Meta and 3DPrinting Meta (I have less than 2000 reputation on both sites, so I don't have full editing privileges). Pressing the <kbd>E</kbd> key to edit a community wiki post doesn't work; it only shows the grayed-out post and doesn't take you to the edit page.  This also applies to your own posts, as I found on Meta SO.

This applies to your own posts on both main sites *and* per-site metas: you're unable to edit any post which you can edit on your own without having to suggest edits (own posts or community wiki posts with 100+ rep) with keyboard shortcuts, if you don't have enough reputation to make binding edits.

[A test wiki.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/97500/259373)  You have to actually click the "edit" button.  Can we fix this?

Comment: I don't think this report is quite right.  I can use the keyboard shortcut to edit community wiki posts on Meta SO, but not the non-CW question on that Gaming link (note that your test link isn't on a meta site).  Perhaps it's broken in certain conditions where you don't have full edit privileges?

Comment: @RyanM Yeah, it's for sub-2K users only, I guess.  You have nearly 10K on SO.  I'll fix that.

Comment: This bug is actually much wider in scope. It occurs for *any* post on *any* site, where you are able to edit it bindingly but don't have enough reputation to use the inline editor (which requires full editing privileges). I was able to reproduce in all such conceivable cases (both own and wiki posts on both main and meta sites with <2k rep). In cases where you can/must suggest edits, it does work, though: on main sites with <100 rep, it works on community wiki posts.

Comment: This may have something to do with attempting to load the inline editor on all posts one can edit bindingly when the E key is pressed, but users without full editing privileges can't use the inline editor, so it fails.

Comment: It's happening for me on [the new private beta](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com) for *all* posts; I don't have edit privileges there.