# Keyboard shortcut for Edit does not work does work on per-site metas when you do not have full edit privilege

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, keyboard-shortcuts

### Editing on meta sites

On per-site Meta pages, you cannot edit most posts until you get [the full edit privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). Trying to edit one shows this message:

> Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.

Thus while you can only do suggested edits, on per-site Metas that can only be done on:

- Community wiki posts
- Your own posts - since you can always change those

## The keyboard shortcut

The keyboard shortcut <kbd>e</kbd> starts editing a post.

## The problem

Pressing <kbd>e</kbd> on *any post* on a per-site Meta does nothing. Even your own posts or community wiki ones. I can only recreate this on per-site Meta pages where I do not have full edit privilege, it works fine if I do have full edit privileges.

Seems like the suggest edit restriction is applied on the keyboard shortcut and it applied wrong so it always takes precedence, even when you should be able to edit a post.

Demonstration. Note that the sudden grey-ish background shows up when a post is selected due to keyboard actions. In this case, it is due to pressing <kbd>e</kbd>:

[image: Short video showing an answer of mine where I cannot edit with the keyboard shortcut but I can click the "Edit" button under the post and it works.]

Comment: Related: [<2k users can't edit own posts or community wiki posts with keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356718/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel a straight duplicate, I'd say. Also [wow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356718/2k-users-cant-edit-own-posts-or-community-wiki-posts-with-keyboard-shortcuts#comment1198427_356718) for some reason I though I tested main sites but apparently I didn't. Yeah, also doesn't work on main sites where you don't have full edit privilege.

Comment: (unrelated to this but...didn't I leave a comment already? I'm pretty sure I posted a comment, then dupe closed my question and my comment was gone. I re-posted it from Textarea Cache. Did I just forget to actually click the post button the first time?)

Comment: I didn't have time to properly check it, I'm glad you did :)

Comment: It could be considered a strange feature, but yes, it should be consistent. There shouldn't be any difference between clicking "Edit" and pressing "E".

Comment: Re *"Pressing e on any post on a per-site Meta does nothing."*: Something does happen if the browser is set up for it: For example, in Firefox, if option *"Search for text when I start typing"* [is enabled](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2022/06/29/setting-up-firefox-on-a-new-system/#keyboard-navigation).